# App Framework Panels and Scrolling Divs

Tags: frameworks, scroll

In an Intel XDK App Framework panel.

How to make a text remain fixed at the top (below a `Default App Header`) and above some other content, that in the `Content` area below, that scrolls into and disappears?

```
Default App Header

MyHeader

Content
```

Currently no matter what I set position and y-indexes to, I can´t get anything to do this simple task.

The entire panel seems to scroll in unison meaning both `Content` and `MyHeader` end up scrolling behind`Default App Header` together as a single linked piece of content.

I need `MyHeader` to stay put and `Content` to touch scroll up and disappear behind it.

I have tried making `MyHeader` a `<div>` with every possible position attribute including fixed.

I have tried making a panel inside of a panel.

I have made my own panel and tried to workaround every possible way I could think of.

The closest I have gotten is disabling the .panel auto scroll and adding it to the div inline but overflow:"scroll" makes a scroll bar which doesn't work and is ignored in touch screen android.

Comment: Found this but doesn't seem to work?

http://app-framework-software.intel.com/api.php#scroller

Answer (score 0):

You add this to the DIV you want to scroll:

```
$("#ID").scroller({
             verticalScroll:true,
             horizontalScroll:false,
             autoEnable:true});
});
```

Here is working example: http://jsbin.com/difuje/8/edit

works on ios and android